# How to handle large volume of filewatcher events without any delay in processing

Tags: c#

To handle large volume of file watcher events, I have implemented the below code in my file watcher.

I have copied a folder to a watched location The folder has around 40K files and folders in it. The issue is the queue items are not getting processed immediately. The processing happening in a period of time. ie The folder copying  took around 40 minutes. But the processing queue took around 4-5 hours from the beginning of the file copying

I am expecting the events to be processed immediately after copying the folder.

Here is my FileProcessor class:

```
class FileProcessor
{
    private Queue<string> workQueue;
    private Thread workerThread;
    private EventWaitHandle waitHandle;

    public FileProcessor()
    {
        workQueue = new Queue<string>();
        waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(true);
    }

    public void QueueInput(string filepath)
    {
        workQueue.Enqueue(filepath);

        // Initialize and start thread when first file is added
        if (workerThread == null)
        {
            workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work));
            workerThread.Start();
        }

        // If thread is waiting then start it
        else if (workerThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
        {
            waitHandle.Set();
        }
    }

    private void Work()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string filepath = RetrieveFile();

            if (filepath != null)
                ProcessFile(filepath);
            else
                waitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    private string RetrieveFile()
    {
        if (workQueue.Count > 0)
            return workQueue.Dequeue();
        else
            return null;
    }

    private void ProcessFile(string filepath)
    {
        // Some processing done on the file

    }
}
```

It is used whenever the FileSystemWatcher.Created event is raised:

```
FileProcessor fileprocessor = new FileProcessor()

void onCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        fileprocessor.QueueInput(e.FullPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of processing is being done by your FileProcessor?  I think that probably largely determines your bottleneck.

Comment: @jon - In ProcessFile method, I will send file creation events to another application.

Comment: What is that other application doing before it returns back to `ProcessFile`?  If it is doing large amounts of processing before returning, you may want to look into making the other application multi-threaded.

Comment: @jon ,my file watcher will send message to other application using pipes. The other application is not multithreaded. but my file watcher is not expecting any response, just will send messages to other application. I will try to see any bottle neck between the process.

Comment: @jon - you  are right, the "other" application is single threaded. so that is the issue. I am wondering how can I accept your solution.

Comment: I'll make a legit "answer" and yuo can accept that, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you still have a single thread processing your `Work` function, your bottleneck is probably there.  That thread will only be able to process as fast as `ProcessFile` can get through the queue.  If `ProcessFile` takes a while to complete, it will definitely cause a bottleneck.

In your case, you mentioned that `ProcessFile` is simply sending events to another application.  You should check to see how that application is processing those events.  I'm guessing that it is performing all of the processing of those events before returning.

You may want to look into making your other application queue up the events it receives, so that it can return back to the caller quickly.  Aside from that, you will want to look into making it process those events in a multi-threaded manner, or find ways to maximize the efficiency of how those events are processed, otherwise you just shift the bottleneck to a new queue.